# Problem at deriving Bachelier formula with interest rates

Tags: options, stochastic-calculus, pricing, models

In the Bachelier model, I have difficulties with a certain step. I want to figure out the distribution of $S_T$, which is the price process in the Bachelier model.

So far I could state that ($\mathbb{Q}$ is the EMM):
\begin{eqnarray}
dS_t = r S_t dt +  \sigma W^\mathbb{Q}_t \label{SDE2}
\end{eqnarray}
and with that 
\begin{eqnarray}
S_T = S_0 e^{rT} + \int\limits_{0}^{T}\sigma e^{r(T-s)} dW^\mathbb{Q}_s
\end{eqnarray}
Now I have found a book that states that $S_T$ has distribution:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_T \sim  \mathscr N \left(S_0 e^{rT}, \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2-\sigma^2e^{-2rT}}{2r}} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

I do not understand why this should be, maybe my skills in stochastic integration are not sufficient.

Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: This is a direct application of Ito's isometry: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry it gives you the mean (= 0) and variance ($= \int f^2(u)du$) of a Wiener integral $\int f(u) dW(u)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by @byouness, using [Itô's Isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), we get:
$$\begin{align}
V(S_T)&=V^{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\int_0^T\sigma e^{r(T-s)} dW^\mathbb{Q}_s\right)
\\[9pt]
&=E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\left(\int_0^T\sigma e^{r(T-s)} dW^\mathbb{Q}_s\right)^2\right)-{\underbrace{E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\int_0^T\sigma e^{r(T-s)} dW^\mathbb{Q}_s\right)}_{=\int_0^T\sigma e^{r(T-s)} E^{\mathbb{Q}}(dW^\mathbb{Q}_s)=0}}^2
\\[-9pt]
&=E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\int_0^T\sigma^2 e^{2r(T-s)} ds\right)
\end{align}$$
The remaining integral is deterministic, thus:
$$V(S_T)=\sigma^2\left[-\frac{e^{2r(T-s)}}{2r}\right]_{s=0}^{s=T}=\sigma^2\left(\frac{e^{2rT}-1}{2r}\right)$$
Note that your result is correct up to a minus sign. This is probably because the Bachelier dynamics for the stock price are also known as an [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process), which is normally defined with a minus sign in the drift, i.e.:
$$dS_t = \color{red}{-}r S_t dt +  \sigma W^\mathbb{Q}_t$$
in which case the volatility is given by the expression in your original post.